# Excel-DNA - Shortcut Ctrl + Letter

Tags: excel-dna

In my XLL, I would like to have my command be assigned the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.
With the following code, I was able to assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>. Is there a way to only assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + a letter.

`[ExcelCommand(ShortCut = "^U")]
        public static void CtrlU()
        { //Code
}`

Thanks,
Guillaume

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
[ExcelCommand(ShortCut = "^u")]
public static void DoBeep() => Console.Beep(400, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Govert. I had my letter in Uppercase, that's why I had to use Ctrl + Shift + U. When I put my letter in lowercase, it works.